# Hypothesis test to determine if mean is greater

Tags: performance, statistics, mean, p-value, hypothesis-test

I have a performance testing suite that tests Chrome browser versions (Telemetry). I'm trying to determine if one version is faster/slower or not significantly different from another for a given test.

For each test run I am provided with: avg, std, count, max, min, sum.

I can compare two test runs (e.g. between two browsers) and I am given: delta avg, % delta avg, delta std, % delta std, ... etc. I am also given the p-value (the probability that the Histograms are NOT significantly different), the z-score (aka standard score: the number of standard deviations between the Histogram average and the reference Histogram average) and the U-statistic (a number produced and consumed by the Mann-Whitney U hypothesis test).

How can I say with an X% certainly that one browser is slower/faster or not different from the other given these test statistics?

I was thinking of just checking p-value < 0.05 and if so, comparing the avgs. But this seems too simple.

Any help much appreciated.

---

**Update:**

If I re-run the tests, I get +/- 10% for the % delta avg between two browsers so looking at avg and p-values is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have to choose what kind of test you want to perform (parametric or non-parametric). I wouldn't use the z-test because I suppose you estimate the std.

1. If your data are normal and they have equal variance you can perform a [t-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Independent_two-sample_t-test)(parametric). If they don't have equal variance you can use Welch's t-test.
2. If they are not normal you should perform the  [Mann-Whitney test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) (non-parametric). However, mann-whitney tests only if the distributions are different between each other and not their means. If you are lucky and they have the same variance then you can make inferences about the mean.

Make sure in the statistical software you are using you are performing a one-sided test, so you actually see which browser is slower/faster. Pay attention to the fact that if you reject the hypothesis avg(X)>avg(Y) it doesn't mean that avg(Y)>avg(X). It means that statistically avg(Y)>=avg(X).

Finally, you have to perform the test using X confidence level to be X% sure about your result. To state that simpler, check if the p-value<1-X. This is not valid if you perform a normality test first and then a t-test, then you are less than X% sure about your result!

With the values you have available you can perform all the tests mentioned above.

Comment: My data doesn't look normal (by looking at the histograms) but then again, there are only 5 sample execution times in each sample. The variance is also not the same between the two browsers.

The U-statistics only tell me that the two samples are different and nothing about which browser is faster. What can I do to infer which one is faster considering their variances are not the same?

Comment: You need a bigger sample with 5 executions it's not advisable to perform any statistical test.

Comment: The Mann-Whitney test you link tests for sample populations of size 5. What would you recommend in this situation?

Comment: My opinion is to gather a bigger sample (how big is relative some people are happy with a sample above 30) and obtain better estimates of the mean and std. I would expect the browsers to have similar std. Then see if one of the above tests applies in your case.